# ImageView collisions

Tags: android, android-imageview, collision

In my game, I have rectangular `ImageView`'s, falling down from top of the screen. At the bottom there is another `ImageView` which can be moved with the accelerometer.

Now I want to check, whether the `ImageView`'s, that are falling from top have a collision with the `ImageView` at the bottom. How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to do something like this by drawing bitmaps on a surfaceview? Then collision detection is easy.

Comment: sry i dont know anything about that. Can you pls send me links with tutorials for it?

Comment: Here is one: http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html   Althought just google "android surfaceview tutorial" and you will find a million others. Youtube videos too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure you can get the to collide, but still you can use getMeasuredWidth() and Height() to determine your square bounding box. then just see if any of the two square's edges are in opposing bound-boxes...

```
if((square1.x > square2.x && square1.x < square2.x+square2.width) && (square1.y > square2.y && square1.y < square2.y+square2.height))
//collision happened
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This function detects collisions between 2 ImageViews

```
public boolean collision(ImageView a, ImageView b){
    float bl = a.getY();
    float bt = a.getX();
    float br = a.getWidth() + bl;
    float bb = a.getHeight() + bt;
    float pl = b.getY();
    float pt = b.getX();
    float pr = b.getWidth() + pl;
    float pb = b.getHeight() + pt;
    if (bl <= pr && bl >= pl && bt >= pt && bt <= pb) {
        return true;

    } else if (br >= pl && br <= pr && bb >= pt && bb <= pb) {
        return true;
    } else if (bt <= pb && bt >= pt && br >= pl && br <= pr) {
        return true;
    } else if (bb >= pt && bb <= pb && bl >= pl && bl <= pr) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```